# MVC - Pass List via ViewBag to View

Tags: model-view-controller, view

I have a viewbag that has a list of items in it.

```
    ViewBag.ProgList = resultlst;
```

I am not sure why when I do the following in the view it is not able to retrieve the values.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Progist)

{ 



  item.ProgID 



}
```

The result simply shows item.ProgID without any actual values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the @ symbol before your text like this:

```
@item.ProgID
```